# Opengl 3.3 rendering nothing

Tags: opengl-3

I'm trying to create my own lib that can simplify code, so I'm trying to write the tutorials that we can found on web using my lib but I'm have some trouble and I don't know why it's rendereing nothing.
so this is my main file

```
#include "../../lib/OpenGLControl.h"
#include "../../lib/Object.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sgl;

int main(){
    OpenGLControl sglControl;
    sglControl.initOpenGL("02 - My First Triangle",1024,768,3,3);
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    //trconfigurações do triangulo
    vector<glm::vec3> vertices;

    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f));
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f));
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    Object triangle(vertices);

    do{
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        triangle.render(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glfwSwapBuffers();

    }
    while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}
```

and this is my Object class functions.

```
#include "../lib/Object.h"

sgl::Object::Object(){
    this->hasColor = false;

}

sgl::Object::Object(std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices){
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        this->vertices.push_back(vertices[i]);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3),&vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

sgl::Object::~Object(){
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDeleteBuffers(1,&(this->vertexBuffer));
        glDeleteBuffers(1,&(this->colorBuffer));
}



void sgl::Object::render(GLenum mode){
    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0, // The attribute we want to configure
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    cout<<vertices.size()<<endl;
    glDrawArrays(mode, 0, vertices.size());
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


}

void sgl::Object::setColor(std::vector<glm::vec3> color){
    for(int i = 0; i < color.size(); i++)
        this->color.push_back(color[i]);
    glGenBuffers(1, &(this->colorBuffer));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->colorBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3),&color[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    this->hasColor = true;
}

void sgl::Object::setVertices(std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices){
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        this->vertices.push_back(vertices[i]);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3),&vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

the tutorial that I rewtriting is it:

```
/*

    Copyright 2010 Etay Meiri

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

    Tutorial 03 - First triangle
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO;

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[3];
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 03");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
      return 1;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

if some one can find the error please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in constructor when I call de function glbufferdata I was sending the wrong data, the right way to do it is that:

```
sgl::Object::Object(std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices){
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        this->vertices.push_back(vertices[i]);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3),&(this->vertices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```